# updateQuery from subscribeToMore updates cache but not query and UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I've got a following code in my component:

```
  const {loading: queryLoading, error: queryError, data: queryResult, subscribeToMore} = useQuery(GET_ITEMS);
  const unsubscribe = subscribeToMore({
    document: SUBSCRIBE_ITEMS,
    updateQuery: (prev, {subscriptionData: {data}}) => {
      const previous = prev.getItems;
      if (!data) return previous;
      return [data.getItems, ...previous];
    }
  });
```

`updateQuery` function executes properly, `data.getItems` structure from subscription matches the `previous` from query. The problem is that query doesn't execute again nor UI gets updated.

Cache seems to be updated properly. After executing query I've got the items in my cache with following structure:

```
Item:1
Item:2
Item:3
```

After subscribing, I've got another item in my cache:

```
Item:1
Item:2
Item:3
Item:4 // comes from subscription
```

Comment: Did you find the solution for this? I'm having the same issue. Did you try `const previous = cloneDeep(prev.getItems)`?

Comment: @OmairNabiel no, I didn't find a solution for that. Regarding your idea, I checked the reference for newly created array and it's different

Comment: For me the problem was, that I was not consuming the props directly but a copy of prop. Adding a separate watcher for that fixed the issue for me